# How can i solve $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log\left(1+(\sin x)^2\right)}{e^x-\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to solve this limit:
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log\left(1+(\sin x)^2\right)}{e^x-\cos x}$$

I tried to do:
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log\left(1+(\sin x)^2\right)}{e^x-\cos x} = $$
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\left(o(\sin x)^2+(\sin x)^2\right)}{1+o(x)+x-(1-\frac{x^2}2+o(x^2))} = $$
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2+o(x^2)}{o(x)+\frac{x^2}2+x} = $$
I left out a lot of simplifications in the middle of the calculation but as far as I got it should be right.

At this point I looked at the solution to the exercise, which is the following:
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2+o(x^2)}{o(x)+x} = $$
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{x+o(x)}{o(1)+1} = 0 $$

I can't understand according to which properties of the small o it is possible to carry out this simplification

Comment: Hint: the last factor in$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+\sin^2x)}{e^x-\cos x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+\sin^2x)}{\sin^2x}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\lim_{x\to0}x\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{e^x-\cos x}$$is computable by the definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x^2/2=o(x)$, in fact $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{2x}=0$, hence $o(x)+x^2/2+x=x+o(x)$.
Now you get
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+o(x^2)}{x+o(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x(x+o(x^2)/x)}{x(1+o(x)/x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x+o(x)}{1+o(1)}=0 $$
The last step is justified by $f(x)o(g(x))=o(f(x)g(x))$.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of $o(x)$ ... or more precisely. When we write the following
$$f(x)=o(x),$$
we mean that $\lim_{x\to{0}}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$.

A general case is when $g(x)$ is a infinite small (which means $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)=0$ ), we write $$f(x)=o(g(x))\tag{1}$$ if and only if $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0.$$

Note that when we write $o(g(x))$ alone (because I only tell you the definition of equation (1) ), we means a expression $f(x)$ satisfying $f(x)=o(x)$.

The properties he use in the exercise is
$$\frac{o(x^2)}{x}=o(x)$$

To proof this, we need to rewrite it using its definition:
$$\frac{o(x^{2} )}{x} =o(x)\Leftrightarrow \text{If a function} \ f\ \text{satisfies} \ \lim\limits _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f( x)}{x^{2}} =0,\ \text{then} \ \lim\limits _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f( x) /x}{x} =0$$
And this is apprarent.

Comment: By the similar way we can define $f(x)=O(g(x))$ by $\lim_{x\to0}=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: But how x^2/2 is removed from the 3° to 4° limit?

Comment: Because $\frac{x^2}{2}=o(x)$. You can verify that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2/2}{2}=0$. And $o(x)+o(x)=o(x)$, which also can be easily verified by definition of $o(x)$.

Comment: The concepts of $o(x)$ and $O(x)$ are used to absorb and neglect higher-order terms, leaving only the main term. This is a fundamental concept in calculus.

For example, in the expression $x^2 + x^4$, the term $x^4$ is much smaller than $x^2$ because $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^4}{x^2}=0$. Therefore, we can express it as:
$$x^2 + x^4 = x^2 + o(x^2)$$

Alternatively, you can also write $x^2 + x^4$ as:
$$x^2 + x^4 = x^2 + 0 \cdot x^3 + o(x^3) = x^2 + o(x^3)$$

Answer (score 3):

You could calculate
$\;\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\log\left[1+(\sin x)^2\right]}{e^x-\cos x}\;$ by using the following notables limits:

$\lim\limits_{y\to0}\dfrac{\log(1+y)}y=1\;\;\;,\;\;\;\;\;\;\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}x=1\;\;\;,$

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^x-1}x=1\;\;\;,\;\;\;\;\;\;\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{1-\cos x}x=0\;\;.$

Since $\;\,\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\log\left[1+(\sin x)^2\right]}{(\sin x)^2}\underset{\overbrace{\;\;\text{by letting }\;\\\;\;y=(\sin x)^2}}{=}\;\lim\limits_{y\to0}\dfrac{\log(1+y)}y=1\;\,,$
it follows that

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\log\left[1+(\sin x)^2\right]}{e^x-\cos x}=$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left\{\!\dfrac{\log\left[1+(\sin x)^2\right]}{(\sin x)^2}\cdot\left(\dfrac{\!\sin x}x\!\right)^{\!2}\cdot\dfrac x{\frac{e^x-1}x+\frac{1-\cos x}x}\!\right\}=$

$=1\cdot1^2\cdot\dfrac0{1+0}=0\,.$

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about [power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series)?

Like,

$\ln(1+x)=x - \frac{x^2}2 + \frac{x^3}3 - \frac{x^4}4 + \frac{x^5}5 - \frac{x^6}6 + O(x^7)$
(converges when $|x| \le 1$)

$e^x=1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + O(x^6)$
(converges everywhere)

Where, $O(x)$ or $O(x^n)$ is used to represent omitted higher‐order terms in power series.

$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2+O(x^2)}{O(x)+x} =\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x+O(x)}{O(1)+1}$ [as $x\to 0\Rightarrow x \ne 0$. We divide numerator and denominator by $x$]

Comment: I'm studying the first order ones only like:
e^x = 1+x+o(x)

Comment: No problem $O(x)$ is representing all other terms till infinity.

Comment: So how do you explain that semplification ?

Comment: this does not answer the question. OP is asking for a clarification of a step not for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing how $\log(1+(\sin x)^2) \longrightarrow \log(1+(\sin 0)^2) = \log(1+0^2) = \log(1) = 0$ and $e^x - \cos x \longrightarrow e^0 -  \cos 0 = 1 - 1 = 0$ as $x \to 0$, I would probably suggest using [L'Hôpital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule):

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log(1+(\sin x)^2)}{e^x - \cos x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}[\log(1+(\sin x)^2)]}{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}[e^x - \cos x]} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{1+(\sin x)^2}}{e^x + \sin x} = \frac{\frac{0}{1}}{1} = 0$.